# Of all the books ever published in English, what percentage are available for NLP training?

Tags: nlp, books, corpus

I notice a lot of NLP models are trained on news articles and Wikipedia content and some books. I wonder if NLP models would be better if they were trained on more books. I assume we don't have datasets/corpus of all books published in English for example. Is this true? Does anyone have any idea what percentage of books published in English are available as NLP training data?

Comment: Have you tried Project Gutenberg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are much more complex than this in reality.

Obviously Wikipedia and a few other datasets are used mostly because they are quite large and easily available and free. But there is a huge variety of corpora in various languages and for various tasks. There are several semi-commercial sites, for example the [Linguistic Data Consortium](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/language-resources/data) or [ELDA](http://www.elda.org/en/catalogues/catalogue-language-resources/).

So as mentioned earlier, of course there is no such dataset of all books in the English language:

- It's impossible, there are probably hundreds of new books in English published every minute.
- It would be extremely expensive, since it basically contains all the content of all the libraries in the world (btw if this corpus was free, all the libraries would be bankrupt).

The closest to this is [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/), which compiles a lot of books which fell in the public domain (so not recent ones).

But anyway it wouldn't be as useful as you imagine, because things are more complex because it depends what the model is for: one doesn't train a model on literature for suggesting options in corporate emails, for example. There are two main 'types' to take into account: the *genre* (e.g. book, email, social media, letter, scientific paper, news ...) and the *domain* (legal, biomedical, political, ...).

There are also a lot of other parameters to take into account:

- When the text is written/published. Shakespeare's English is not exactly the same as the one spoken today. New words/terms appear every day.
- Regional dialect: UK, US, Australia... There is even a new "EU English" recently.
- Quality

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing research using text datasets for a couple of years and have not seen one for books written in English. One reason could be the copy right considerations when including a book text in a dataset.

You can check a list of the most used text datasets in the literature on [paperswithcode.com](https://paperswithcode.com/datasets?mod=texts&page=1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Sakher. Given how important training data is for NLP and how the highest quality training data may well be in books that are proofread and edited,  I find it interesting that the unrealized opportunity of using the corpus of all books published is not more widely discussed. Clearly, there are copyright considerations, but those could be addressed. Is there any discussion around this topic somewhere? I don't seem to know where to start to look.